# Xamarin Android: Application crashed after clear data in Settings

Tags: crash, xamarin.android, launching

This is the error I have copied from the logcat. I don't know why the application crashed after clear the data in the App Settings screen.

```
    02-20 17:22:29.980 839-1094/? I/InputReader: Apps event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.44 ] when=459940281000
02-20 17:22:29.980 839-1093/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering Apps to: action: 0x4
02-20 17:22:29.980 839-1093/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering Apps to: action: 0x0
02-20 17:22:29.980 839-1093/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering Apps to: action: 0x0
02-20 17:22:30.010 839-1094/? I/InputReader: Apps event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=459972752000
02-20 17:22:30.010 839-1093/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering Apps to: action: 0x1
02-20 17:22:30.010 839-1093/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering Apps to: action: 0x1
02-20 17:22:30.130 12257-12257/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.Appsjet.app [ userId:0 | appId:10499 ]
02-20 17:22:30.190 839-1223/? V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause: onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.Appsjet.app/create]
02-20 17:22:30.200 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonodroid.so 0x42a78da8
02-20 17:22:30.200 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonodroid.so 0x42a78da8
02-20 17:22:30.230 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Using override path: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__
02-20 17:22:30.230 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.230 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.230 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.230 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.250 12257-12257/com.Appsjet.app A/monodroid: No assemblies found in '/data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__' or '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
02-20 17:22:30.270 839-1486/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.Appsjet.app (pid 12257) (adj 0) has died.
02-20 17:22:30.320 12271-12271/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.Appsjet.app [ userId:0 | appId:10499 ]
02-20 17:22:30.360 839-1223/? V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause: onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.Appsjet.app/create]
02-20 17:22:30.380 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonodroid.so 0x42a79d68
02-20 17:22:30.380 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonodroid.so 0x42a79d68
02-20 17:22:30.410 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Using override path: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__
02-20 17:22:30.410 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.410 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.410 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.410 12271-12271/com.Appsjet.app W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.430 12271-12271/? A/monodroid: No assemblies found in '/data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__' or '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
02-20 17:22:30.450 839-2717/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.Appsjet.app (pid 12271) (adj 0) has died.
02-20 17:22:30.490 12285-12285/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.Appsjet.app [ userId:0 | appId:10499 ]
02-20 17:22:30.520 839-1223/? V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause: onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.Appsjet.app/create]
02-20 17:22:30.540 12285-12285/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonodroid.so 0x42a7a548
02-20 17:22:30.540 12285-12285/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonodroid.so 0x42a7a548
02-20 17:22:30.570 12285-12285/? W/monodroid: Using override path: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__
02-20 17:22:30.570 12285-12285/? W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.570 12285-12285/? W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.570 12285-12285/? W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/com.Appsjet.app-6/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.570 12285-12285/? W/monodroid: Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
02-20 17:22:30.590 12285-12285/? A/monodroid: No assemblies found in '/data/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__' or '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Appsjet.app/files/.__override__'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
02-20 17:22:30.610 839-4777/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.Appsjet.app (pid 12285) (adj 0) has died.
02-20 17:22:30.610 839-4777/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{4359bc20 u0 com.Appsjet.app/md58d07a10744293905ae52d7d8dd7a82d6.SplashScreen t27}: app died, no saved state
02-20 17:22:30.630 839-1223/? V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause: onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.Appsjet.app/pause]
```

I don't have a clue what is causing. I am using Xamarin Studio PCL project. The app will run if I run and install the app through the Xamarin Studio.

Comment: This happens it the build is in debug mode. Try to build in release mode and then clear data to test.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the Android Project > Properties > Android Options > Packaging, uncheck "Use Fast Deployment" option

To clarify as requested (George): Apparently, Xamarin loads the libs as user data when you run it in debug mode (or export a debug version maybe?). So when you clear the data of your app, you delete stuff that isn't deleted in a normal release version. Turning off the Fast Deployment forces Xamarin to put your files in the right place

Comment: Could you add some context? What does this option do, and how does unchecking it fix the problem?

Comment: To clarify as requested: Apparently, Xamarin loads the libs as user data when you run it in debug mode (or export a debug version maybe?). So when you clear you the data of your app, you delete stuff that isn't deleted in a normal release version. Turning off the Fast Deployment forces Xamarin to put your files in the right place.

Comment: 2021 this is still working, I love you man